# Main Menu Slider Navigation

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to set up a main navigation slider that could have unlimited items in it and you can scroll off the side of the screen and as you can slide them by touch for a mobile device.

Has anyone seen any tutorials or seen any thing online that could help with this type of menu

Comment: Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I didn't realize i didn't ask a question. thanks Ejay